# ClassCastException when using PriorityBlockingQueue

Tags: java, multithreading, message-queue

I'm trying to make a simple message manager for my game. However, I'm getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.ClassCastException: MessageManagement.Message cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.siftUpComparable(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.offer(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.add(Unknown Source)
at MessageManagement.MessageManager.EnqueueMessage(MessageManager.java:69)
```

The initialization code is:

```
MessageManager messageManager = new MessageManager();
messageManager.start();

//send bootstrap message
CJournal.Journal(Main.class, "Testing messanger: ending bootstrapping message to messagemanager");
Message boot_strap_message = new Message();
boot_strap_message.mflag = EEventMachine.EM_BOOTSTRAP;
messageManager.EnqueueMessage(boot_strap_message);
```

And the actual message manager is:

```
public  class MessageManager extends Thread {

    @Override
    public  void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while (true)
        {

            if (!messagesQueue.isEmpty())
            {
                //pull message from queue
                Message message = messagesQueue.remove();

                //dispatch messages according to their type
                switch(message.mflag)
                {
                case EM_BOOTSTRAP:
                    CJournal.Journal(MessageManager.class, "Messaging system working properly.");
                default:
                    CJournal.Journal(MessageManager.class, "Dispatch Message Trashed");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static PriorityBlockingQueue<Message> messagesQueue = new PriorityBlockingQueue<Message>();

    public static void EnqueueMessage(Message message)
    {
        //Error happens here
        messagesQueue.add(message);
    }
```

Why am I getting this error and what do I need to do to fix it?

Comment: Why are you using `PriorityBlockingQueue`?

Answer (score 1):

Per [PriorityBlockingQueue's javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html)

> A priority queue relying on natural ordering also does not permit insertion of non-comparable objects (doing so results in ClassCastException).

Your `Message` class needs to implement [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

```
class Message implements Comparable<Message> {
    public int compareTo(Message m) {
        int comparisonResult = //comparison logic. 
        return comparisonResult;
    }
}
```

Per [Comparable#compareTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T))'s javadoc, `compareTo`

> Set a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer if this message is less than, equal to, or greater than (respectively) the specified object.

Your other option is to supply a [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to `PriorityBlockingQueue`.

Answer (score 0):

[Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html) is clear:

> **public class PriorityBlockingQueue extends AbstractQueue
>   implements BlockingQueue, Serializable**
>
> An unbounded blocking queue that uses the same ordering rules as class
>   PriorityQueue and supplies blocking retrieval operations. While this
>   queue is logically unbounded, attempted additions may fail due to
>   resource exhaustion (causing OutOfMemoryError). This class does not
>   permit null elements. A priority queue relying on natural ordering
>   also **does not permit insertion of non-comparable objects (doing so
>   results in ClassCastException)**.

You have to implement the [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface.

```
class Message implements Comparable<Message> {

   public int compareTo( Message o ) {
      int diff = ...;
      return diff;
   }
}
```

or implement the [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface and give it to the constructor of PriorityBlockingQueue.

```
class MyComp implements Comparator<Message> {

   public int compare( Message l, Message r ) {
      int diff = ...;
      return diff;
   }
}
```